# Can't understand this way of accessing 2-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, casting

I run across this snippet of code, and found very strange that it manages to print 5. I can't understand why that casting to int* manages to make it basically a 1 dimensional array. Can someone explain?

```
int main()
{
    int v[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int* c = (int*)v;
    printf("%d\n", c[4]);
}
```

Comment: This program has undefined behaviour. `v` is not a pointer to `int` and is not compatible with one. The program may appear to do anything.

Comment: Does this help? [Does C99 guarantee that arrays are contiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832970/does-c99-guarantee-that-arrays-are-contiguous)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Having incompatible type does not preclude a cast being valid

Comment: @M.M The cast itself is valid, the subsequent dereference is not.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. on what basis do you make that claim?

Comment: @M.M There is nothing in the standard that allows accessing an array element through a pointer to an array cast to the pointer of its element type. On top of that, the array being accessed is the first element of v, which has length 3, and we are trying to access an element that is beyond its end.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I agree that accessing beyond the first 3 elements has issues but I think accessing the first row is well-defined. We can deduce from the casting rules that the result of the cast points to the same memory location of the first int and dereferencing an `int *` that points to an int is well-defined

Comment: @M.M There is a special provision in the standard for a pointer to the first member of a struct, suitably converted, being the same as a pointer to the struct itself and vice versa. There is no such provision for arrays. I don't think pointing to the same memory location is relevant here. `&v[0][3]` definitely points to the same memory location as `&v[1][0]`, but you cannot dereference the former, only the latter (the standard specifically prohibits that). You can compare these pointers and they must compare equal!

Comment: @M.M BTW I'm not even sure any more that an array and its first element must have the same address. Can you point out where it is specified? :)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. it follows immediately from the fact that arrays can't have padding

Comment: @M.M So far I don't see why an array cannot have padding (e.g. to store a descriptor inaccessible to the program) at the beginning. Perhaps it cannot but the standard language is too convoluted for me to see it immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's talk about how array subscripting works.

First, remember that the array subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - that is, given an address `a`, offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result:

```
   +---+
a: |   |
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | <--- a + i
   +---+
```

This works for two reasons:

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  If `T` is itself an array type (such as with `int [2][3]`, or "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`"), then you wind up with a pointer to an array type (`int (*)[3]`, or "pointer to 3-element array of `int`).

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account - if `p` is an `int *` and stores the address of an `int` object, then `p + 1` yields the address of the *next `int` object*, not the next byte.  If `p` is a pointer to a 3-element array of `int` (`int (*)[3]`) and stores the address of an array, then `p + 1` yields the address of the *next 3-element array of `int`*.

Graphically:

```
 int         int *            int [3]    int (*)[3] 
 +---+                        +---+            
 | 1 |  <--- p                | 1 | <--- p
 +---+                        + - +
 | 2 |  <--- p + 1            | 2 |  
 +---+                        + - +
 | 3 |                        | 3 |
 +---+                        +---+
 | 4 |                        | 4 | <--- p + 1
 +---+                        + - +
 | 5 |                        | 5 |
 +---+                        + - +
 | 6 |                        | 6 |
 +---+                        +---+
```

The picture on the left is a sequence of `int` objects with `int *` pointers, and the picture on the right is a sequence of `int [3]` objects with `int (*)[3]` pointers.

So what's happening is that you're getting the address of the first element of `v`, but you're treating it as an `int *`, not as an `int (*)[3]`:

```
int* c = (int*)v;
```

You're basically taking the picture on the right and pretending it's the picture on the left.  So `c[4]` corresponds to the 5th element in the sequence, which in this case is `5`.

Now, this behavior is *undefined* - `int (*)[3]` and `int *` are not *compatible types*, and attempting to access elements of `v` this way is not guaranteed to work.  What would be safer would be to use

```
int *c = &v[0][0]; // int * = int *
```

There's no casting to get around incompatible types, and you get the exact same effect.

Comment: The type compatibility does not have anything to do with it