# How to pass a double array to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to solve this problem the whole day:

How do I pass a double array to a function?

Here is an example:

```
int matrix[5][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10} };
```

And I wish to pass this matrix to function named `eval_matrix`,

```
void eval_matrix(int ?) {
    ...
}
```

I can't figure out what should be in place of `?`

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I know that an array can be passed just as a pointer, but what about a double array (or triple array?)

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be usable as an array the compiler has to know the inner stride of the array, so it's either:

```
void eval_matrix( int m[5][2] ) { ...
```

or:

```
void eval_matrix( int m[][2], size_t od ) { ... /* od is the outer dimension */
```

or just:

```
void eval_matrix( int* p, size_t od, size_t id ) { ... /* ditto */
```

In any case it's syntactic sugar - the array is decayed to a pointer.

In first two cases you can reference array elements as usual `m[i][j]`, but will have to offset manually in the third case as `p[i*id + j]`.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the 3rd possibility.

Comment: What about `int**`? The question asked how to pass `int [][]` to a function. They are oh-so-different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943909/manipulate-multidimensional-array-in-a-function

Answer (score -1):

You should not pass the whole matrix, instead you should pass the pointer, however, you should pass the size too... this is how I would do it, assuming it is always pairs [2].

```
struct pair {
   int a, b;
};

struct pair matrix[] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10} };

void eval_matrix(struct pair *matrix, size_t matrix_size) {
  ...
}

eval_matrix(matrix, sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(struct pair);
```