# appending arrays in a function with C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, struct

Say I have a few arrays like this:

```
hi=["h","i"];
how=["h","o","w"];
are=["a","r","e"];
you=["y","o","u"];
```

and I want to pass these to a function and have the function print out (in this way...my function is doing similar operation, but not exactly) all of the arrays such they show.

```
hihowareyou
```

I'm thinking something like this:  But, somehow pack the arrays in a struct??

```
void printit(char *data){
  for (char i in data; i<sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);i++){
    do some print operation on data[i];
  }
}
```

I've tried this pseudo code in various iterations with structs with varying (although persistent) degrees of failure.
As such, I feel like I'm misunderstanding how to pass collections of arrays to something to be worked on from a fundamental perspective.

Comment: Are you able to accomplish this *without* having to pass the data to a function, just having the data defined in the function doing the printing?  If you can't do that, being able to pass things to a function isn't going to help that much.

Comment: You could give it a try in actual code, rather than pseudocode... from what you have here it's not even clear if you know the differences between a `char` and a string, or `char *` and array of `char`, or a string literal and a character constant...

Comment: something like [this](http://ideone.com/4Trj6s) ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY whoa momma!  That's it...That's just fine, right there.  What is that...maneuver?? called?  I need to Google it.

Comment: `sizeof(data)` will just give you the size of a pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a double array to a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220833/how-to-pass-a-double-array-to-a-function-in-c)