# C++ Passing Dynamic Array Determined by Parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-length-array

This function has been asked a few times on here but I am interested in a particular case.  Is it possible to have the size of the array passed defined by an additional argument?

As an example, let's say I want a function to print a 2D array.  However, I the array may not have the same dimensions every time.  It would be ideal if I could have additional arguments define the size of that array.  I am aware that I could easily switch out the `n` for a number here as needed but if I have more complex functions with separate header files it seems silly to go and edit the header files every time a different size array comes along.  The following results in `error: use of parameter 'n' outside function body...` which I understand but would like to find some workaround.  I also tried with `g++ -std=c++11` but still the same error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int n, int A[][n], int m) {
    for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    int A[][3] = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9},
        {10,11,12}
    };

    printArray(3, A, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Supposedly, this can be done with [C99](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434395/c-passing-dynamically-sized-2d-array-to-function) but I cannot figure out how with C++.

Comment: This is not possible in Standard C++. VLA is a C-only feature, or non-standard compiler extensions. [Link to related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013444/are-variable-length-arrays-there-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
void printArray( int(&arr)[M][N] ) {
  for(int i=0; i < M; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < N; j++) {
      std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

if you are willing to put the code in a header file.  As a bonus, it deduces `N` and `M` for you.

Comment: This works wonderful when in the main file, but I am having troubles when I put it in a header.  Where it is complaining about 'M' and 'N' not being declared.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @cdeterman the body of the function must be in a header file.  You may have to `#include <cstddef>` to get `size_t`, or replace `size_t` with `unsigned` if arrays of size `2^32` are large enough.