# Initialiser list passed as function parameter for array

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

How do I make this work:

```
void foo(uint8_t a[]) { ... }

foo({0x01, 0x02, 0x03});
```

It gives me an error:

```
error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '1'
                                                     ^
```

Comment: The problem would have been clearer had you avoided the confusing `uint8_t[]` parameter "type" and written the more accurate `uint8_t*` instead. :)

Comment: Sorry yeah I'd normally use the pointer form but I was wondering if the compiler might perform some magic that I didn't know about if I used the array syntax instead.

Comment: Nope, 100% equivalence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers so far haven't addressed the main problem with the question: In the signature

```
void foo(uint8_t a[])
```

`a` is not an array, but a pointer to a `uint8_t`. This is despite the fact that the declaration of `a` makes it look like an array. This is even pointed out by the error message:

```
cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}'
```

So, in the same way you are not allowed to do this:

```
uint8_t *a = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03}; // Eek! Error
```

You can't call `foo({0x01, 0x02, 0x03});` With the signature above.

I suggest you take some time to read up on C-style arrays and how they are [not first-class citizens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c) in C++.

From the answer you posted to your own question, it seems that you are looking for a function that works for fixed-size arrays. But don't pass it by value! I recommend using the following declaration:

```
void foo(std::array<uint8_t, 3> const &a);
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me, I had to change the function signature but it's actually better in my case as it statically checks the array length:

```
void foo(std::array<uint8_t, 3> a) { /* use a.data() instead of a */ }

foo({0x01, 0x02, 0x03}); // OK

foo({0x01, 0x02}); // Works, at least on GCC 4.9.1. The third value is set to zero.

foo({0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04}); // Compilation error.
```

Comment: C-style arrays suck at *everything*. Always use std::array over them if possible.

Comment: Maybe you can use a template like `template<int size> void foo(std::array<uint8_t, size> a){/*...*/}`...(I haven't tried this way before..)

Comment: @Shindou not in this case, `size` parameter cannot be inferred.

Comment: @ForEveR I've just tested. we have to call it like `foo<size>({/*...*/});` to make it work

Comment: @Shindou: Which is what he just said

Comment: So this is weird... now when I try this I don't get a compilation error for the wrong size array. Can anyone confirm whether they do or not, and whether you should. Could be a GCC bug (I'm using 4.9.1).

Comment: Actually after testing it seems that it allows shorter initialiser lists and fills them in with zeros, but longer ones cause an error. I may have lied in my original answer and have actually tested it with a longer list.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.
Just construct

```
uint8_t a[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
```

and call `foo(a)`.

Or just use `std::array`, that is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
void foo(uint8_t a[]) { ... }
```

is a function that takes a `uint8_t*`, not an array - arrays are decayed to pointers when used as function arguments. The issue is that an initializer list (like `{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}`) cannot be converted to a `uint8_t*`.

If what you want is to pass an arbitrary number of `uint8_t`s to `foo`, the simple solution is to use the new [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> a) { ... }

foo({0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05}); // OK - a has 5 elems in it
```

Or you could take a variadic pack and construct an array from it internally:

```
template <typename... Args,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              all_true<std::is_convertible<Args, uint8_t>::value...>
              >>
void foo(Args... elems) {
    uint8_t a[] = {elems...};
    // ...
}
```

That has slightly different usage:

```
foo({0x01, 0x02, 0x03}); // error
foo(0x01, 0x02, 0x03; // OK - a has 3 elems in it
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo(std::array<uint8_t, 3>{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}.data());`

Comment: The std::array is created before the function and lives until the function returns.