# Why does this Code use "call by reference"?

Tags: c

In the below code, there is a problem that I didn't understand. In the lines of these:

```
gcd = GCD(n, A); 
lcm = LCM(n, A);
```

Despite I didn't use the pointers, the array A[n] elements has changed after the GCD function. Thus, the second function didn't work correctly. So, if I reversed the order of the above two lines, this time the GCD function wouldn't work correctly. What is my mistake?

```
/*
    Finding the greatest common divisor and the least common multiple in an array.
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int GCD(int n, int A[]);
int LCM(int n, int A[]);
int main()
{
    int n, gcd, lcm;
    printf("Length of the array?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int A[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Element #%d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    gcd = GCD(n, A); 
    lcm = LCM(n, A);

    printf("\ngcd: %d\nlcm: %d\n", gcd, lcm);

    return 0;
}

int GCD(int n, int A[]) // Greatest common divisor
{
    int gcd = 1, j = 1, flag, ones = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        flag = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] % j == 0)
            {
                A[i] /= j;
                flag++;

                if (A[i] == 1)
                    ones++;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0 || j == 1)
            j++;
        else
            gcd *= j;

        if (ones == n)
            return gcd;
    }
}

int LCM(int n, int A[]) // Least common multiple
{
    int lcm = 1, j = 2, flag = 0, ones = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (A[i] == 1)
            flag++;

    if (flag != 0)
        return 1;

    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] % j == 0)
            {
                A[i] /= j;
                flag++;

                if (A[i] == 1)
                    ones++;
            }
        }

        if (flag == n)
            lcm *= j;

        if (flag == 0)
            j++;

        if (ones == n)
            return lcm;

        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int A[]` in a parameter list means `int *A`. You're using pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C are converted, in most of the cases, to a pointer to the first element of the array itself. And more in detail arrays passed into functions are always converted into pointers.

Here a quote from [K&R2nd](http://alvand.basu.ac.ir/~dezfoulian/files/Programming/Prentice%20Hall%20-%20The%20C%20Programming%20Language-%20Brian%20W.%20Kernighan,%20Dennis%20M.%20Ritchie,%202nd%20ed.,%20ISBN%20.pdf):

> When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the
>   location of the initial element. Within the called function, this
>   argument is a local variable, and so an array name parameter is a
>   pointer, that is, a variable containing an address.

Writing:

```
int GCD(int n, int A[]);
```

has the same meaning as writing:

```
int GCD(int n, int * A);
```

So despite you are not writing it explicitly it is as you are passing a pointer.

For more I really suggest reading [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c).

Moreover, you can find other answers on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Any explanation that involves "the name of" isn't right. It's like saying `int i = 42; double d = i;` works because "the name of an integer is converted to a floating point number".

Comment: It is an explanation, you just have to remove "name of".

Comment: @melpomene ok thanks for your tip

Comment: Thank you! So, is only way to fix this, am i need to create a new array and copy elements of A[n] to the new array? (Then i can send two same arrays to the two different functions.)

Comment: @LionKlan if you need to modify the array into the function, yes

Comment: it's not "converted", but *decayed*

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc the standard does not use the term "decay".  It uses "converted" (for expressions) and "adjusted" (for parameters).  OP's first sentence is mostly correct, although a reader could get a false impression that it is an explanation for the rest of the answer

Comment: @M.M what do you suggest in order to improve my answer?

Comment: @granmirupa doesn't really matter as there are many duplicates. Maybe remove the first sentence though or clarify that adjustment and conversion are different

Comment: @M.M maybe now it is a better answer that explain this specific case without too much divagation.