# What is the difference between 'char *' and 'char (*) [100]'?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings, memory-address

```
int main()
{
    char word[100];
    char* lowerCase;

    scanf("%s", word);

    lowerCase = toLowerCase(&word);
    printf("%s", lowerCase);
}

char * toLowerCase(char *str)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

I am getting a warning while executing the above code.
the warning is

```
try.c: In function 'main':
try.c:16:26: warning: passing argument 1 of 'toLowerCase' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  lowerCase = toLowerCase(&word);
                          ^~~~~
try.c:4:7: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[100]'
 char* toLowerCase(char *str);
```

I am not able to understand why this warning is coming?
if i am passing (word) to the function there is no warning, but when i execute the following code the output is same:

```
printf("%d", word);
printf("%d", &word);
```

If the address is same then why this warning?

Comment: `char` is a single character, `char[100]` is a block of 100 characters. These are different types and therefore a pointer to each is a different type of pointer . You designed your function to expect a pointer to a single character

Comment: You should be using `toLowerCase(word)`.

Comment: `word` already denotes a pointer; i.e., a `char *`. You may pass it w/o the reference operator `&`. For `char *p = "some text";`, `p` points to the starting address of the string, whereas `&p` means the address of the pointer variable (a `char **`), not the address where its pointing at.

Comment: @M.M char is a single character, char[100] is a block of 100 characters. These are different types -> aggreed,
therefore a pointer to each is a different type of pointer?
You designed your function to expect a pointer to a single character?

Comment: @WeatherVane how does that affect my question?
i am asking a totally different thing

Comment: Because without a function prototype the compiler knows nothing about it. The warning is in `main`, before the function definition. So when receiving warnings about function arguments, the first step should be to declare them correctly (which they should be anyway).

Comment: @WeatherVane I have used function prototype in my code, but haven't uploaded it here. the warning is not because of that.

Comment: That is one reason you are asked to post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the complete code. Then readers *know* you have a function prototype, and which matches the function definition.

Comment: @P__J__'s answer teaches it well. This, however, is adjacently related and provides some more insight into array parameter types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c/51527502#51527502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char x[100]`

Array `x` decays to pointer:

`x` - pointer to the char (`char *`)

`&x` - pointer to a the array of 100 chars (`char (*)[100]`);

`&x[0]` - pointer to the char (`char *`)

all of those pointers reference the same start of the array, **only the type is different**. The type matters!!.

You should not pass the `&x` to the functions which expect (`char *`) parameters.

Why type matters?:

```
char x[100];

int main()
{
    printf("Address of x is %p, \t x + 1 - %p\t. The difference in bytes %zu\n", (void *)(x), (void *)(x + 1), (char *)(x + 1) - (char *)(x));
    printf("Address of &x is %p, \t &x + 1 - %p\t. The difference in bytes %zu\n", (void *)(&x), (void *)(&x + 1), (char *)(&x + 1) - (char *)(&x));
    printf("Address of &x[0] is %p, \t &x[0] + 1 - %p\t. The difference in bytes %zu\n", (void *)(&x[0]), (void *)(&x[0] + 1), (char *)(&x[0] + 1) - (char *)(&x[0]));
}
```

Result:

```
Address of x is 0x601060,    x + 1 - 0x601061   . The difference in bytes 1
Address of &x is 0x601060,   &x + 1 - 0x6010c4  . The difference in bytes 100
Address of &x[0] is 0x601060,    &x[0] + 1 - 0x601061   . The difference in bytes 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/SLJ6xn