# Why memoization doesn't require a pointer?

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming

For example in this code, which works fine, memoization done with an array not a pointer to an array. (int mem[] instead of int* mem)

```
int fibonacci(int n,int mem[]){
    if(n < 3)
    return 1;   

    if(mem[n])
    return mem[n];

    mem[n] = fibonacci(n - 1, mem) + fibonacci(n - 2, mem);
    return mem[n];
    } 

int climbStairs(int n){
    int mem[50] = {0};
    return fibonacci(n + 1, mem);
}
```

I don't see how, when one of the functions returns, how can the caller function of the returned function
have the data to previous mem[n]. Isn't the functions array supposed to be deleted when the function returned? How can after that function returned, another function that a caller function calls can have that value?

Note: This is a solution to Climbing Stairs in leetcode. Written by me.

Comment: An array parameter is automatically treated as a pointer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Comment: it is passed as a pointer in fibonacci.  memory is allocated on the 'stack' in climbStairs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6567846/3365922 because `int mem[]` and `int* mem` are same

Answer (score 0):

When using `[]` in a function argument, it is a pointer.

```
int foo(int x[])
```

and

```
int foo(int *x)
```

are 100% equivalent.

However, this would be something else:

```
int foo(int x[10])
```