# array elements are changed for sееmingly no reason

Tags: c

I simplified my code as much as possible:

```
#define MAX_BUF 4096
#define MAX_ARGS 200

int main() {
    char **argv;
    argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAX_ARGS);
    
    get_command(argv);

    printf("arg0:%s\n", argv[0]);
    cd(argv, NULL);
    printf("arg2:%s\n", argv[0]);
}

void cd(char *argv[], char *old_pwd) {
    char cwd[MAX_BUF];
    printf("arg1:%s\n", argv[0]);
}

void get_command(char *argv[]) {
    char input[MAX_BUF];

    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    argv[0] = strtok(input, " ");
    argv[1] = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

`get_command` reads the input of the user, let's say it's `aa bb`, it would then save `aa` to `argv[0]` and `bb` to `argv[1]`. Let's note that `argv` is an array whose memory has been allocated dynamically inside `main`. Then, I pass `argv` to `cd`, but the elements of `argv` seem to change? The only thing I did there is declare a new string, and if I remove this declaration `argv` doesn't change and it works correctly. So my guess is that what I am doing is somehow undefined behavior, but I don't get **how**.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because it's a pointer...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an array as an argument to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Be aware that all pointers to the local variable `input` in `get_command` will point to garbage as soon as the `get_command` has ended. Local variables cease to exist as soo as their function is over.

Comment: @user202729 even if I replace ```*argv[]``` with ```**argv[]``` the problem is not solved. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, thank you! now I get it! this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_command` sets `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` to point to places within `input`. But, in the C model of computing, `input` ceases to exist when `get_command` returns, meaning the memory used for it is released and may be reused for other purposes.

Then the pointers in `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` become invalid, and the contents of the memory they pointed to may change, which likely happens when `cd` executes.

`get_command` should use `malloc` to allocate memory for the command or its parts. For good form, program should also free that memory when it is done using it.

Comment: Yes this answers my question! thank you!

Comment: More correctly, it's the Algol60 model of computing ("Look, mama, I invented something! If I stack things likes so I can unstack them in reverse order without messing everything up!") ;-) [Friedrich L. Bauer](https://cacm.acm.org/blogs/blog-cacm/185577-the-life-of-a-computer-pioneer/fulltext) must have played with woodblocks as a child.