# Using an array in multiple functions

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I have an array that was created within a function, I want to use it in a different function but can't seem to figure out how.

If it helps at all, here is the function with the array in it. I want to use roll[] within a different function.

```
int roll_5_array(void)
{
    int i = 0, roll[5]; //Declaring array

    for (; i < 5; i = i + 1) //Repeat 5 times
    {
        int outcome = 0;
        outcome = roll_die(); //Roll die

        roll[i] = outcome;
    }

}
```

With my current knowledge, I can only come up with a few possible solutions to this:

- Make the array global, which seems unnecessary and redundant.
- Pass the array as a pointer, if that's even possible.

Comment: Do you want to use it in the `roll()` function? If so, then yes -- pass an `int*` and a `size_t` length. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You declared a local array with automatic storage duration

```
int roll_5_array(void)
{
    int i = 0, roll[5]; //Declaring array
```

It will not be alive after exiting the function.

If you want to return it from the function you need to allocate it dynamically as for example

```
int * roll_5_array(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int *roll = malloc( 5 * sizeif( int ) );

    //...
    return roll;
}
```

To do so you need to include header `<stdlib.h>`.

You will need to free the array using a pointer that points to the allocated array by means of calling function `free` when the array will not be required any more.

Pay attention to that your original function returns nothing though its return type is not void

```
int roll_5_array(void)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways

1. Returning pointer to the array

```
int *func(void)
{
    int *arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(*arr));
    /* ... */
    return arr;
}

int *func(void)
{
    static int arr[5];
    /* ... */
    return arr;
}
```

Or by passing the pointer to pointer.

```
void func(int **ptr)
{
    int *arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(*arr));
    /* ... */
    *ptr = arr;
}

void func(int **ptr)
{
    static int arr[5];
    /* ... */
    *ptr = arr;
}
```