# What do these type of declarations mean

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have come across some declarations in C, unable to understand what they mean.

What do `*const` and `*restrict` mean here? These are used in `aio_suspend` function.

```
const struct aiocb *const aiocb_list[]
```

```
const struct timespec *restrict timeout
```

Comment: Did you read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict

Comment: The variable `aiocb_list` is an array (of unspecified size) of constant pointers to `aiocb` structure objects, and each element in the array is constant. Learning about [the clockwise/spiral rule](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) might be useful.

Comment: The variable `timeout` is a ["restricted"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) pointer to a constant `timespec` structure.

Comment: `restrict` in particular doesn't mean much without any context - please post the complete function. Since `restrict` is a relation between a specific pointer (usually parameter) and other pointers and/or file scope variables.

Comment: `aiocb_list[]` is NOT an array, it's a pointer, due to parameter type adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

For clarity let's see them seprately:

1. `const struct aiocb *const aiocb_list[]`:

   - `const` applied to `struct aiocb`: This indicates that the pointers in the `aiocb_list` point to constant struct `aiocb` objects, allowing you to use these pointers to access the data as read-only.
   - `const` applied to `aiocb_list`: The array itself is constant; the pointers stored in it cannot change.
2. `const struct timespec *restrict timeout`:

   - `const` applied to `struct timespec`: Data pointed to by `timeout` is constant (read-only).
   - `restrict` applied to `timeout`: A hint to the compiler that there's no aliasing (no other pointers pointing to the same memory), allowing for certain optimizations.

**Note**: For `const` applied to `struct aiocb`, this does not prevent non-const views of the same objects from existing elsewhere in the program. The objects themselves are not inherently constant or read-only, but `aiocb_list` enforces a read-only view through these pointers.

Comment: "its address cannot change" -> "pointers stored in it can't change". Addresses of objects themselves can never be changed regardless of `const`.

Comment: "Data pointed to by these pointers is constant (read-only)" is incorrect.  In fact the `aiocb_list` gives a read-only view of the `struct aiocb` objects, but nothing prevents non-const views of the same object from existing elsewhere in the program.  The objects are not constant or read-only.

Answer (score 1):

### [1] `const struct aiocb* const aiocb_list[];`

Here

- `aiocb_list` is being declared. It is an array.
- it is an array of constants
- the constants are pointers
- each element of the array is a pointer to `aiocb`, a `struct`
- the array itself is also constant, due to the first `const`
- since it is not being initialized it must be part of something, like a parameter list, since it is declared `const`

So it is a constant array of `const` pointers to a `struct`

### Example

Here is a program that uses such construct

#### output

```
  function got 4 pointers
  Values are
  S
  O
  S
  O
```

#### code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct aiocb
{
    char what;
};

struct aiocb* action(
    size_t size, const struct aiocb* const aiocb_list[]);

int main(void)
{

    const struct aiocb data[4] = {
        [0] = {'a'},
        [1] = {'O'},
        [2] = {'S'},
        [3] = {'d'},
    };

    const struct aiocb* const list[] = {
        &data[2],
        &data[1],
        &data[2],
        &data[1],
        &data[0]
    };
    action(4, list);
    return 0;
}

struct aiocb* action(
    size_t size, const struct aiocb* const aiocb_list[])
{
    printf(
        "    function got %llu pointers\n    Values are\n",
        size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
        printf("    %c\n", aiocb_list[i]->what);
    return NULL;
}
```

#### A second example: using `typedef`

This is the same code, just using a global `typedef` for the `struct`. In general it is easier to read and saves a ton of `struct aiocb` typing

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char what;
} Aiocb;

Aiocb* action(size_t, const Aiocb* const[]);

int main(void)
{
    const Aiocb data[4] = {
        [0] = {'a'},        [1] = {'O'},
        [2] = {'S'},        [3] = {'d'},
    };

    const Aiocb* const list[] = {
        &data[2], &data[1], &data[2], &data[1], &data[0]};
    action(4, list);
    return 0;
}

Aiocb* action(
    size_t size, const Aiocb* const aiocb_list[])
{
    printf(
        "    function got %llu pointers\n    Values are\n",
        size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
        printf("    %c\n", aiocb_list[i]->what);
    return NULL;
}
```

Note that these assignments in `main`

```
    list[0] = NULL; // error: array elements are const
    const Aiocb* other[5] = {0};
    // error: list can not point to other places
    list = other;
```

would not compile, since all array elements are `const` and `list` is also `const`

### [2] `const struct timespec *restrict timeout;`

Here `timeout` is being declared as a restricted pointer to a `timespec` `struct`. And is constant.

`restrict` is a commitment by the programmer that, during its lifetime, the pointer so declared will be the only one to access its target. The access to the target is *restricted* to this pointer only.

This warranty gives the compiler an opportunity to optimize the code.

A good example is in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict):

```
int foo(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a = 5;
    *b = 6;
    return *a + *b;
}
 
int rfoo(int *restrict a, int *restrict b)
{
    *a = 5;
    *b = 6;
    return *a + *b;
}
```

And the possible generated code

```
; generated code on 64bit Intel platform:
foo:
    movl    $5, (%rdi)    ; store 5 in *a
    movl    $6, (%rsi)    ; store 6 in *b
    movl    (%rdi), %eax  ; read back from *a in case previous store modified it
    addl    $6, %eax      ; add 6 to the value read from *a
    ret
 
rfoo:
    movl      $11, %eax   ; the result is 11, a compile-time constant
    movl      $5, (%rdi)  ; store 5 in *a
    movl      $6, (%rsi)  ; store 6 in *b
    ret
```

And we see that the compiler, knowing that no one but `a` and `b` will be pointing to the targets inside the function, can return `11` and skip the `add` before return.

In some scenarios `restrict` can enable huge savings in execution time and code size, since the compiler can reorder things or skip operations in large loops.

Comment: "It is an array"  No, it's not.  Parameter type adjustment applies here; it's actually a pointer.

Comment: This is `C`  afer all. The `[]` means at the end means something. Without them the compiler says: `(parameter) const Aiocb* const aiocb_list` and it is a pointer. With them compiler says `(parameter) const Aiocb* const aiocb_list[]`. Anyway *arrays decay to pointers*. But an array it is, declared in `main` in the example: `const Aiocb* const list[]`

Comment: Talking about the function argument (`aio_suspend` function in the question, `action` in your answer).  It [is a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6567742/103167).

Comment: @BenVoigt I do not see the point. It is declared in main. It is an array. It is `C`. It gets into the function as an argument, in `C`. Being an array argument in a `C` program, you can say it is a pointer. So what? It is an example of how to use the array, declared in `main`, as in the question. It is just a fake `struct`, not even the real `aiocb`. Please see it as it is.

Comment: "_When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the initial element. Within the called function, this argument is a local variable, and so an array name parameter is a_ **pointer**_, that is, a variable containing an address._" -- K&R "5.3 Pointers and Arrays" ... Who's wrong? Dennis Ritchie or arfneto?

Comment: @Fe2O3 `const Aiocb* const list[]`  declares an array, for me, Dennis, Brian and others. For you, sure you can read the program and the comments as you wish. It is declared in `main` using an initializer list.