# How can I pass a multidimensional array as a pointer in c

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-to-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c)

so I have char `buffer[4][50]`

I need to pass it to a method `void SetBuffer(char **buffer)` or at least that's how i think it's suppose to be formatted.

so I do `SetBuffer(buffer);`?  In the method I need to set each element so

`void SetBuffer(char **buffer)`
`{`
`strncpy(buffer[0], "something", 50);`
`strncpy(buffer[1], "something else", 50);`
`}`

how can this be accomplished properly?

Comment: this looks more C to me then C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ way would be to use a proper container (e.g. `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::string`) as appropriate.

OTOH, if there's a particular reason to fall back on arrays, using pointers (as you already do) and passing in the dimensions explicitly are one way to do it..

Comment: +1 for "use a proper container". I would have answered similarly.

Comment: best way to do it, I agree as I did a bit of research and saw that it was a dangerous design to use multidimensional array in this case

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways:

The easiest is:

```
void SetBuffer(char[][50] buffer)
{
strncpy(buffer[0], "something", 50);
strncpy(buffer[1], "something else", 50);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: this is a C answer. Your answer looks correct to me, but a better approach is something like:

```
#define BUFFER_DIM_1   4
#define BUFFER_DIM_2   50

int    i;
char **buffer;

/* Create an array of pointers to the lower level */
buffer = malloc(BUFFER_DIM_1 * sizeof(char *));
for (i=0; i<BUFFER_DIM_1; i++) {
    buffer[i] = malloc(BUFFER_DIM_2 * sizeof(char));
}
```

You can then use as you suggest.

for the braver of heart, you could go with only two mallocs and some cleverer pointer work:

```
#define BUFFER_DIM_1   4
#define BUFFER_DIM_2   50

int    i;
char **buffer;

/* Create an array of pointers to the lower level */
buffer    = malloc(BUFFER_DIM_1 * sizeof(char *));
buffer[0] = malloc(BUFFER_DUM_1 * BUFFER_DIM_2 * sizeof(char));
for (i=1; i<BUFFER_DIM_1; i++) {
    buffer[i] = buffer[i-1] + BUFFER_DIM_2 * sizeof(char);
}
```

Finally, don't forget to free all this memory up when you no longer need it.

Comment: That's fine in C, but in C++ use dirkgently answer