# c++ Error when Testing library

Tags: c++, arduino

I am creating an Arduino library which takes two constructors for a personal project of mine, but for some reason I keep getting an error which is specific to types, first let me show you how the structure goes. so here is my files:

this is the header file:

```
#ifndef iGA_H
#define iGA_H
 class iGA {
   public:
         getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[]);
   private:
         int _soundA[];
         int _soundB[];
         int _parentId[];
 }
```

the cpp file:

```
#include <iGA.h>
iGA::getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[])
{
  _soundA = soundA;
  _soundB = soundB;
  _parentId = parentId;
 }
```

And this is how im pretty much calling the constructor in the sketch, within the setup() function:

```
#include <iGA>
iGA iga;
void setup() {
  iga.getParameters(r, r1 , r2);
}
```

and here is the error:

```
In file included from /home/bargros/Dropbox/iGA__NewBild/iGA__NewBild.ino:34:0:/home/bargros/Arduino/libraries/iGA/iGA.h:10:58: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'getParameters' with no type [-fpermissive]getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[]);
```

I know the error has something to do with argument types or maybe im calling the constructor wrongly but I also tried calling it like this:

```
iGA iga = getParameters(etc,etc,etc);
```

im relatively new to c++ and im a little clueless as to what this error is telling me. Does anyone have any sort of idea of why this happens?

Comment: your getParameters should return something. **HINT**: There should be something **before** iGA::getParameters

Comment: `getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[]);` should at least be `void getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[]);`.

Comment: Tried to add void, still get the same error - will try what @FirstStep suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe two issues:

**Issue 1**: Your function should return something right? you may want to set it as `void` if it just meant to assign the parameters to the private members (it is a `setter` and not a `get` in your case). Add `void` in the proper locations both inside the class and when you write its definition.

**Issue 2**: I think that you can't send an `array[]` as a parameter. And I assume that you already know the size. You need, instead, to send a pointer that points to the first element of the array along with the size of the whole array. Then, once you receive the parameters, for every private member, you create a new array with the size received (or just fill the private member directly) and fill the values by iterating the received array using the pointer received.

**Edit**: I just checked and passing `int array[]` should be fine. So fixing issue one will fix your problem. See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c) for further documentation.

Comment: @bar glad it helped :) please upvote if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have to be explicit that a function doesn't return anything, which you do by saying it returns `void`:

```
getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[]);
```

needs to be

```
void getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[]);
```

and

```
iGA::getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[])
```

needs to be

```
void iGA::getParameters(int soundA[], int soundB[], int parentId[])
```