# Passing array to function in c++ somewhat confused with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Does

```
void function(int *parameter){}
```

do the same thing as

```
void function (int parameter[]){}
```

?
And could the first one also be used to pass in variable pointers not arrays? Kind of confused.

Comment: So you searched STACKOVERFLOW and found nothing about it? You are the first one ever to have this question? :/

Comment: Didn't find anything specifically comparing these two. Maybe I didn't do enough searching?

Comment: Prbably, but it's okay, [this answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c), next time be more careful! :)