# Struggling to pass an array created in one function to a sort function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, iteration

I am currently working on a project where we have to create an array of 1000 elements then pass it to another function to sort it. Everything I have seen online shows you how to pass it from main to another function, but not the other way around.

Please take a look at my code and help me pass `Ar[1000]` from `Array()` to `ISort` and ultimately main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void Array()//function to make array
{
    int Ar[1000];//creating array     
    int i = 0;//random variable to be element #     
    int counter = 0;// counter variable     
    int randnum;//variable to old random number     
    srand(time(NULL));//seeding rand with time

    while (counter != 1000)    
    {    
        randnum = rand();     
        Ar[i] = randnum;     
        cout << Ar[i]<<endl;     
        counter++;
    }          
}

void ISort(int Ar[1000])//Iterative sort
{     
    int count = 0;//another counter variable     
    int count2 = 0;//counter variable # 3 because nested loops    
    int j=0;//Temp index # similar to i     
    int temp; //Temp variable to help switch elements     
    while (count != 1000)
    {
        if (Ar[count] < Ar[j])
        {
            temp = Ar[count];    
            Ar[count] = Ar[j];     
            Ar[j] = temp;
        }               
    }
}

/*void RSort(int Ar)//Recursive sort
{

}
*/

int main()
{
    Array();
    ISort();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The array declared in function `Array` is local and will disappear when execution leaves the function.  Either pass array to function or make it as a global.

Comment: In the `main` function, you are not passing an array to `ISort`.  Your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: ... or may Array() function to return an array instead of 'void' (no return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Array` function declaration to:
`int* Array()` and make it return the array `Ar`. And in `main` get the returned value from `Array` function like this:
`int* Ar = Array();` 
and pass it to the function `ISort` like this : `ISort(Ar);`.

Here is an example on [SO passing an array to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14309136/1305969).

Comment: An example of passing the array would be beneficial.

Comment: If you will return a local variable then it will cause UB. It would work if this array was static inside this function, or if it was dynamically allocated.

Comment: My answer has an issue that may cause undefined behaviors as mentioned by @marcinj, i suggest that you take a look at his answer and accept it. Sorry for that and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

`Ar` in your `Array` function will be destroyed once this function finishes, you need to have a way to prevent this, one way is to pass an array by parameter instead of making it function local variable:

```
void Array(int* Ar, int count)//function to make array
{
```

I would also change Your current `ISort` definition to:

```
void ISort(int* Ar, int acount)//Iterative sort
```

where `acount` is number of elements in `Ar`. This is because it makes no difference whether you use `void ISort(int Ar[1000])` or `void ISort(int* Ar)` (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p) for more on this). If you want to preserve array type then you must pass it by reference using: `void ISort(int (&Ar)[1000])`.

Finally changes in `main`:

```
   int Ar[1000];//creating array
    Array(Ar, 1000);
    ISort(Ar, 1000);
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
```

working code is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/678f581f802da85b

You also forgot to increment `count` inside your sorting loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `int Ar[1000]` variable inside an `Array()` function is a local variable. Make it a global variable by moving it out of the function scope:

```
int Ar[1000]; //creating array
// your functions here
int main()
{
    Array();
    ISort(Ar);
    return 0;
}
```

You should also modify the `Array()` function to accept array as parameter as pointed out in the comments below. Please note that I am omitting the array size part as it seems the number of the elements is set to 1000:

```
void Array(int Ar[]){
    //...
};
```

in which case the above code would be:

```
int Ar[1000]; //creating array
// your functions here
int main()
{
    Array(Ar);
    ISort(Ar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't change the `Array` function there will be a *shadow* copy; bad, very bad.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to change Array function a bit:

```
int* Array() {  // change return type to be able to return array you create
   int Ar[1000];
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {  // much better to use for loop than while
      Ar[i] = rand();  // no need to hold another variable for random number
      cout << Ar[i] << endl;
   }
   return Ar; // return the Ar
}

int main() {
    int* array = Array();
    ISort(array);
}
```

Hope that helps. Also there are many other solutions to this but I don't know what exact restrictions your task has. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

EDIT: So I totally forgot about that C arrays are just a plain old pointers... Well then the solution would be like this:

```
void Array(Ar[1000]& array) { // pass array to the function with reference
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {  // much better to use for loop than while
      array[i] = rand();  // no need to hold another variable for random number
      cout << array[i] << endl;
   }
}

int main() {
    int[1000] array = Array();
    ISort(array);
}
```

Sorry for the error but using C style arrays really isn't common in C++ when you can use vectors and maps.

Comment: Returning a pointer to local variable will cause Undefined Behaviour.