# Difference between passing an array as formal parameter as int arr[] and int arr[N] in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I got confused by the accepted answer and the comments below it that are stating opposite things
in [Passing Arrays to Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c).

**As formal parameter of a function** is there any difference between passing an array as `int arr[]` or `int arr[N]`?  In other words, is there a difference between `void foo(int arr[])` and `void foo(int arr[N])`?

Comment: The top answer says that they are equivalent to each other and to `int *`. That's the correct answer.

Comment: You could get the answer yourself by taking the function declarations in your question and have the compiler attempt to distinguish between the two. `const int N = 10; void foo(int arr[]); void foo(int arr[N]);`  You will see it [can't be done](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9efa8e0e0ed5c27)

Comment: The commentators didn't read the answer closely enough. The answer covers all the bases and the comments are irrelevant.

Comment: If all you want is discriminate between different arguments, you must use a reference: `void f(int (&a)[4])` and `void f(int (&a)[8])` are different functions and must be called with arrays of specified size.

Comment: I have no idea why that comment on the top answer has so many votes. It is rude, and is just wasteful really. Even the article the commenter links to agrees with the actual answer!

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` already. Forget that C-style arrays exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `void foo(int arr[])` and `void foo(int arr[N])` are exactly equivalent.  This is because an array as an argument to a function is adjusted to a pointer.  So both of the above translate to:

```
void foo(int *arr)
```

This is specified in section 6.7.6.3p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Function declarators":

> **A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’,**  where  the  type  qualifiers  (if 
>   any)  are  those  specified  within  the `[` and `]` of  the array  type 
>   derivation.   If  the  keyword `static` also  appears  within  the `[`
>   and `]` of  the array  type  derivation,  then  for  each  call  to 
>   the  function,  the  value  of  the  corresponding actual argument
>   shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as
>   many elements as specified by the size expression.

Similar language exists in section 11.3.5p5 the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> A single name can be used for several different functions in a single
>   scope; this is function overloading(Clause 16). All declarations for a
>   function shall agree exactly in both the return type and the
>   parameter-type-list. The type of a function is determined using the
>   following rules. The type of each parameter (including function
>   parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and
>   declarator. **After determining the type of each parameter, any
>   parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be
>   “pointer to T”.** After producing the list of parameter types, any
>   top-leve lcv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when
>   forming the function type. The resulting list of transformed parameter
>   types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis or a function
>   parameter pack is the function’s parameter-type-list.[Note:This
>   transformation does not affect the types of the parameters.

Comment: If `N` is an expression, more than just a simple constant, then the parameter declarations `int arr[]` and `int arr[N]` are not equivalent in C. In the latter, `N` is evaluated, even though the parameter type is adjusted to be `int *arr`. (I am not positive the C standard requires this, but it at least permits it, and both Clang and GCC do it.) For example, `#include <stdio.h>` / `static void foo(int a[printf("Hello\n")]) {} int main(void) { foo(0); }`, prints “Hello”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I never would have guessed that.  I wonder why the grammar allows it?

Comment: It may be more bother than it is worth to change it, because you must allow size expressions in arrays not at the outermost level, as in `int a[][x]`, and those expressions must be evaluated so the called function knows the size. Excepting the outermost dimension might have been a nuisance to deal with in the grammar. Although there are some variations already; `int a[static 4]` in a parameter says `a`  points to a place with at least 4 elements (and hence `a` cannot be a null pointer).