# sizeof operator giving wrong results

Tags: data-structures, sizeof

```
struct val{
int first;
int second;
};
int maxChainLen(struct val p[],int n);
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        val p[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            cin>>p[i].first>>p[i].second;
        }
         cout<<maxChainLen(p,n);
    }
    return 0;
}


int maxChainLen(struct val p[],int n){
    int x=sizeof(p);
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Input
1
5
5  24 39 60 15 28 27 40 50 90
```

Here I am simply finding the `sizeof` of array `p` inside `maxChainLen()` method, which ideally should be `5*size` of `p[0]`, ie- 5*8 = 40bytes.
But `sizeof(p)` and `sizeof(p[0])` both are displaying 8.
I know this is very basic but I have no idea why `sizeof()` is giving wrong results here.

Comment: You pass pointer to val, so this is sizeof pointer

Comment: int arr[100];
cout<<sizeof(arr);

This prints 400;

Comment: Also when i am running a loop from 0 to n-1 for p[], it prints all the values properly; but sizeof(p) gives wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `int maxChainLen(val p[], int n)`  is equivalent to:  `int maxChainLen(val* p,int n)` - the function actually accepts a *pointer* to `val`.
When you call this function, the array you pass *decays* to a pointer.

You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c/49214662#49214662) for exact standard-backed wording.