# Dynamic nested arrays in C++ resulting in cannot convert brace-enclosed initializer list to int

Tags: c++, arduino

I have written a function that takes in a dynamic length array but with fixed inner array size, the second parameter in the function is the length of the parent array. When I try to access the nested values however, I get the issue mentioned above.

```
void myFunc(int arrOfArr, int arrOfArrLen) {
  // try to access
  arrOfArr[0][1]; // expect val2
}
```

example usage

```
myFunc(
  {
    {val1, val2},
    {val3, val4}
  },
  2
);
```

edit: I realize "contextually" obviously an integer has no indexes, but that's how you declare an array it seems...(truthfully in Arduino context) but apparently it's still C++

Here's a runable demo of above from the first sandbox Google returned

http://cpp.sh/5sp3o

update

I did find a solution, it's ugly but it works:

instead of passing in a "raw" nested array as a param, I set it as a variable first eg:

```
int arrOfArr[][3] = {
  {val1, val2},
  {val3, val4}
}
```

Then in the function I do the same thing

```
void myFunc(int arrOfArr[][3], int arrOfLen) {
  // access
}
```

Call it

```
myFunc(arrOfArr, 2);
```

As I said it's ugly but works for me, this is a passing project thing not a low-level dev, maybe will learn it fully later on but not needed in day job.

edit: apparently the thing I was trying to do initially eg. embed an initializer list as a param does not work.

Comment: Hint: `int` is not an array type. You need to be more specific in your function signature. You should also use `std::vector` if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Arrays to Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c)

Comment: @tadman, yeah maybe I should have posted in the Arduino forum instead, but they declare arrays with the int in front

Comment: @J.Schultke I'm reading up on it, thanks for the link

Comment: If it's C++ then `int` alone is not sufficient. Maybe you mean `int*`? In that case you have a 1D array though, not 2D like you want.

Comment: that did change something(ha), but I have a few issues "int[int] for array subscript" and also "no matching function for call to myFunc..." ahh man I've been in the high level language world taken it for granted

Comment: You would have to use `int**` for a 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass a nested array, the declaration may be:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
void myFunc(int const arrOfArr[][N], int arrOfArrLen) {
  // ...
}
```

and you can remove the template argument if `N` is already decided.

```cpp
const size_t N = 3;
void myFunc(int const arrOfArr[][N], int arrOfArrLen) {
  // ...
}
```

but it doesn't work if you pass a brace-enclosed initializer, you can add a overloaded function:

```cpp
template<size_t M, size_t N>
void myFunc(int const (&arrOfArr)[M][N], int arrOfArrLen){
  // attention: int *const*
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, in my frantic Googling, I did find the template stuff and the "overloaded" thing(didn't know that's what it's called), how do you pass in the value? In my solution it's verbose where you have to define an int before passing it into the param call.