# When passing an array as an argument, is the same memory space of the array used, or is a copy made

Tags: c++, c

Consider the following program:

```
void doSomething(char array[5])
{
    char b = 3;
    array[0] = b;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    doSomething(array);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, when passing the array to the `doSomething` function, is a **copy** of the array made and takes up more memory?, or is the **pointer** of the array simply passed, and the very same array is being modified?

Comment: Easy to check: print `array[0]` after the call!

Comment: the 2nd option is true

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c When you pass an array as an argument to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Why don't you just test it? Check the array after calling the function.

Comment: The parameter `char array[5]` is equivalent to `char* array`, and the call `doSomething(array)` is equivalent to `doSomething(&array[0])`. (This should be covered in any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).)

Comment: Also you'd want to be more *specific* about whether you want to ask about C or C++ as they're two distinct and differing languages.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++ language, use `std::vector` not arrays.  The `std::vector` can dynamically expand, can be queried for its size, and passed by reference to functions (with out having to pass an additional capacity parameter).