# Passing an float array to constructor

Tags: c++

I'm working on a school project with C++, I'm using constructors. I will have a basic school system, which will consist on working with students name, student id, student grades (with will be the float array[]) and an optional substitution test.
I'm having problems when assigning the float array to the values I have declared on the main function.

This is the function.cpp file:

```
#include "aluno.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Aluno::Aluno(){
    cout << "Objeto 1 inicializado!\n";
}

Aluno::Aluno(char* name, int rgm, float notas[2], float nota_sub){
    this->nome = name;
    this->rgm = rgm;
    this->notas = notas;
    this->nota_sub = nota_sub;
    cout << "Objeto 2 inicializado!\n";
}

Aluno::~Aluno(){
    cout << "Aluno destruido: " << nome;
    cout << "Objeto destruido!";
}

void Aluno::entrada(){
    cout << "Digite seu NOME: ";
    cin >> nome;
    cout << "Digite seu RGM: ";
    cin >> rgm;
    cout << "Digite sua nota do primeiro bimestre: ";
    cin >> notas[0];
    cout << "Digite sua nota do segundo bimestre: ";
    cin >> notas;
    cout << "Digite sua nota da substutiva: ";
    cin >> nota_sub;
}
```

When attempting to do this->notas = notas I get the following error:

```
expression must be a modifiable lvalueC/C++(137)
```

This is the .h file:

```
#ifndef ALUNO_H
#define ALUNO_H

class Aluno
{
    private:
        char* nome;
        int rgm;
        float notas[2];
        float nota_sub;
    public:
        Aluno();
        Aluno(char* name, int rgm, float notas[2], float nota_sub = 11);
        ~Aluno();
        void entrada();
        void imprime();
        bool aprovado();
};

#endif
```

And the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aluno.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float notas[2] = {5.3, 6.2};

    Aluno aluno1("Nilton", 1904659, notas);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah.  You can't copy-assign arrays.  This is C++ 101.  Use `std::copy`.

Comment: Also note that `float notas[2]` in `Aluno::Aluno` likely doesn't mean what you think it means. See [Passing Arrays to Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c)

Comment: You can't copy  arrays in C/C++ using just `operator=`. You can try `this->notas[0] = notas[0]; this->notas[1] = notas[1];`. Perhaps a shorter notation exists. You would save yourself (and us) the effort if you used `std::array<float, 2>` instead of `float[2]` - then copying would be easy.

Comment: paddy is correct about the syntax error.  You actually have *several* options.  One is to use [std::copy](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/).  Another option is to declare your array without a size: `float notas[]`.  The best option is to use an array container [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), instead of a "raw" array.