# Passing C arrays to functions

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to understand pointers in C and I think I have an okay grasp so far.  I am trying to make sense of arrays and how they are passed to functions.  It is my understanding that when passing an array to a function it is passed by reference and that when passing an array to a function it points to the beginning of the array in memory or the first memory address of the array.  So if I create an array like so:

`char* arr[2] = {"Andrew", "Schools"};`

I could define the following functions to accept this array which is really passing a pointer to the first item in the array:

```
void readSingleArray(char* arr[], int count) {
  for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
}

void readSingleArray2(char** arr, int count) {
  for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

The second function accepts `char** arr` instead of `char* []`. So I understand this as such: *since I have an array of pointers, this is telling the compiler that I want to access a pointer to a char so either way will work.*

Now if I define a multi-dimensional array like so:

`char* arr2[2][2] = {{"Andrew", "Schools"},{"Computer", "Programmer"}};`

I can define the following function:

```
void readMultiDimArray(char* arr[2][2], int count, int count2) {
  for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    for(int x=0; x<count2; x++) {
      printf("%s\n", arr[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

But not this function:

```
void readMultiDimArray2(char** arr, int count, int count2) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    for(int x=0; x<count2; x++) {
      printf("%s\n", arr[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

I read that multi-dimensional arrays are actually single dimensional arrays or one single block of memory and the compiler will figure out how to access the appropriate array items: [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c).  This makes sense to me **so my question is**: *Why can I use a `char** arr` for single arrays but when using multi-dimensional array this won't work.  Because how I see it, no matter what, I only need to access the first memory address of the array since it's always going to be one continuous block of bits*

Comment: I think your examples get a bit difficult because you are using arrays of `char*`, so arrays where the base element is a pointer. First, try to think things trough for situations where the base element is e.g `double`.

Comment: `readMultiDimArray2` will not work properly.  If you did what Jens Gustedt suggested you would see why.

Comment: @JS1 - You are right.  readMultiDimArray2 doesn't compile like I thought it did which throws the entire question off.

Comment: I updated question.  I will also do what @Gustedt mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These function declarations

```
void readMultiDimArray(char* arr[2][2], int count, int count2) {
  for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    for(int x=0; x<count2; x++) {
      printf("%s\n", arr[i][x]);
    }
  }
}

void readMultiDimArray2(char** arr, int count, int count2) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    for(int x=0; x<count2; x++) {
      printf("%s\n", arr[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

are not equivalent and the second function declaration is wrong if you are going to pass an array declared like `char* arr2[2][2];` as an argument of the function. A correct function declaration will look at least like

```
void readMultiDimArray2( char * ( *arr )[2], int count, int count2) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    for(int x=0; x<count2; x++) {
      printf("%s\n", arr[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you have an array declared like

```
T array[N];
```

where T some type then when the array is passed to a function that has the same parameter declaration then it is converted to pointer to its first element. That is it will have type

```
T *ptr;
```

So if you have an array declared like this

```
char* arr2[2][2];
```

then you can redeclare it the following way

```
typedef char * T[2];

T arr2[2];
```

According to the explanation above it will be converted like

```
T *ptr;
```

when it will be passed as an argument.

Now substitute T for its actual type and you will get

```
char * ( *ptr )[2];
```

where `char *[2]` is the type of the element of array `arr2`

Each two-dimensional array is in fact a one-dimensional array elements of which is in turn one-dimensional arrays. That is it is an array of arrays.

Comment: I think I understand why readSingleArray and readMultiDimArray work since you are accessing the first element in the array which happens to be a pointer.  But why does readSingleArray2 work?   Isn't this a pointer to a pointer?  What is the difference between char* arr[] and char**?  Does the compiler resolve this as being equal?

Comment: @Andrew Schools Reread my post.  Array char *arr[2] can be represented like T arr[2]; where T is char *. So when the array is passed to the function it is converted to pointer to its first element T *ptr; Now replace T with char * and you will get char **ptr where char * is the type of objects pointed to by ptr. Thus for example ptr[0] will get an object of type char *..,

Comment: Let me re-read your example a bunch of times so I get a full understanding of what you said.

Comment: @Andrew Schools If something is unclear then ask a question. You may also ask a question in English in my personal forum at www.cpp.forum24.ru in the first section of the forum.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, when we point to an array we want to specify a pointer to the first element of the array.  For a single array of character strings, this type would be char** or char* [].  For a multi-dimensional array of character strings with an inner dimension of 2, this type would be char* (*ptr)[2].  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Andrew Schools  To copy a whole array when it is passed to a function as a parameter is inefficient, Arrays can be very big. So when you declare a function parameter as an array and pass an array designator as an argument then it is adjusted by the compiler to a pointer to its first element, Elements of a two-dimensional array are in turn one-dimensional arrays (rows). So when you pass a two-dimensional array as an argument it is converted to a pointer to its first one-dimensional array element (row).