# Pass a matrix to a function

Tags: c++, matrix, constructor

```
  unsigned char j[4][4];
```

And I want pass this element to the constructor of a **class**, I have a attribute in the class with the same type as the matrix

```
class x{

  private:

    unsigned char x[4][4];

  public:

     x(unsigned char j[4][4]);

};
```

I put values in my matrix j and in the constructor I want equalize j and x like this

```
x(unsigned char j[4][4]){
    x = j;
}
```

but and error appear in the code

**incompatible types in assignment of ‘unsigned char (*)[4]’ to ‘unsigned char [4][4]’**

why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c).

Comment: C way: `memcpy(x,j,sizeof(x))` or `memcpy(x,j,sizeof(j))`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass arrays as arguments like this. You should not be using arrays to begin with. Really, just don't. The problem you're facing is just one problem out of a multitude of problems you will have when using arrays.

Instead, use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that contains another `std::array` (so that it's two-dimensional):

```
#include <array>

class X {
private:
    std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 4>, 4> x;

public:
    X(std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 4>, 4> j);
};
```

In your constructor, just assign:

```
X(std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 4>, 4> j)
{
    x = j;
}
```

or, even better, use a [constructor initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
X(std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 4>, 4> j)
    : x(j)
{ }
```

(Also note that I changed your class name from `x` to `X` (capital.) Don't use conflicting names for classes and variables. It's confusing :-)

If you need your matrix to have a size that's determined at runtime instead of having a fixed size, then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign arrays to each other: they're no `vector`s, which you can assign safely.

You'll have to iterate over that array passed as a parameter and copy its contents:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        this->x[i][j] = argument_called_j[i][j];
```

BTW, to my mind, this `x` variable is a bit confusing because there's a class called `x`.  If you'd like to take a look at how one could build such a class to work with matrices, check out [my project called *Matrix*](https://github.com/ForceBru/Matrix) on GitHub.

Comment: If you're doing it C-style, then you may as well `memcpy(x,j,sizeof(x))` or `memcpy(x,j,sizeof(j))`.

Comment: Traversing with for loops for primitive types would be foolish premature pessimization. Use `memcpy()`.