# CS50 draw function draws only zeros

Tags: c, cs50

This is my first stackoverflow post.

I am doing the CS50 course on edx and currently I am stuck at problem set 3. I am implementing the game of fifteen. The init() function initizalizes the board and the draw function should draw it but there is a problem.

The draw function does not get the values from the init() function. I experimented with it, in the init() function the values are correct, but in the draw function all of them are 0's.

What's the problem?

```
/**
 * Initializes the game's board with tiles numbered 1 through d*d - 1
 * (i.e., fills 2D array with values but does not actually print them).  
 */
void init(void)
{
    //initializing the board
    int board[d][d];
    int x = (d*d) -1;
    //this loop goes trough each row
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        //this goes trough each column
        for(int j = 0; j < d ; j++){
            //this condition handles the case of swapping the 2 and 1 when the grid is even
            if( (d % 2) == 0 && (x == 2) ){
                //assigning the number 1
                board[i][j] = x-1;

                //going to the next column
                j++;

                //assigning the number 2
                board[i][j] = x;

                //setting the x = 0 so the loop can end
                x=0;
            }
            //this happens if the above conditions are not met
            else {
                //assigning the value to the grid
                board[i][j]= x;

                //decrementing the value
                x--;
            }
            //ending the loop
            if(x == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        //ending the loop after the last tile is initialized
        if(x == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Prints the board in its current state.
 */
void draw(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            if(board[i][j] != 0){
                printf("%2i", board[i][j]);
            } else {
                printf("_");
            }
        }

    printf("\n");    

    }
```

Comment: `void init(void)
    {
        //initializing the board
        int board[d][d];` this `board` is local.

Comment: This solved it, thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `board[][]` is a local variable and thus only work inside the `init()` environment.

I'm taking the CS50x course as well, and the `fifteen.c` file they handle us actually already have a `board[][]` variable declared in line 27: `int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];`, which is already global.

So you don't need to create another board, just use the one they handle to us.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it, thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

This might help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Basically everything what you do in your init function (variable names & values) are only valid in this function or block.

To solve this you can either make `int board[d][d];` a global variable by declairing it above the main function like so (highly discouraged!):

```
int board[d][d];

int main(int argc, char** argv){ ... }
```

OR you could give the varibale `board[d][d]` as a reference to your function `draw`. <strike>This works but is inefficient because the whole variable will be copied.</strike>

```
void draw(int board[][]){...}
```

OR you can allocate memory for `board[d][d]` on the heap by using the c command `malloc` see man malloc. Then your code should look something like this.

```
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(board));    //you need to error check this. See man malloc
```

If you do that you only need to pass the Pointer to the Data in your function. This is more efficient because the data stays on the heap memory.

Comment: Arays decay to pointers when passed to functions, so the board will not be copied when passed. Passing a multidimensional arrays has caveats, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c

Comment: Ok i did not know that. Thanks! 
But also in his case? I thought everything you do on the function stack is lost as soon as the function terminates, so C needs to copy the data anyway.