# What is the pointer type of a multidimensional array when passed to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm learning about C and pointers in my university class, and I think I've got a pretty good grasp on the concept except for the similarity between multidimensional arrays and pointers.

I thought that since all arrays (even multidimensional) ones are stored in continuous memory, you could safely convert it to a `int*` (assuming the given array is an `int[]`.) However, my professor said that the number of stars in the definition depends on the number of dimensions in the array. So, an `int[]` would become an `int*`, a `int[][]` would become an `int**`, etc.

So I wrote a small program to test this:

```
void foo(int** ptr)
{

}

void bar(int* ptr)
{

}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][4];

    foo(arr);
    bar(arr);
}
```

To my surprise, the compiler issued warnings on *both* function calls.

```
main.c:22:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type
      'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    foo(arr);
        ^~~
main.c:8:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'ptr' here
void foo(int** ptr)
         ^
main.c:23:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type
      'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    bar(arr);
        ^~~
main.c:13:15: note: passing argument to parameter 'ptr' here
void bar(int* ptr)
         ^
2 warnings generated.
```

What's going on here? How could you change the function calls so one of them would accept the array?

**Edit:** This is *not* a duplicate of [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c) because I'm asking how to change the function calls themselves, not the function signatures.

Comment: There is no pointer equivalent for multi-dimensional arrays. Either make the function accept an array of fixed dimensions, or pass a pointer to the first element and then calculate the displacements withing the function yourself.

Comment: @DYZ So why do both the above functions give warnings when I attempt to compile the program?

Comment: Because you pass a 2D array (an object  of one type) instead of pointers (objects of another type).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers aren't entirely freely convertible. To not get a warning, you'd need a signature like `void foo(int (*ptr)[4])`. You can only replace the first [] with a * when passing an array like that to a function.

Comment: you can also write it as `void foo(int ptr[][4])` but the effect is the same