# How to pass a multidimensional C array to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm learning about C and pointers in my university class, and I think I've got a pretty good grasp on the concept except for the similarity between multidimensional arrays and pointers.

I thought that since all arrays (even multidimensional) ones are stored in contiguous memory, you could safely convert it to a `int*` (assuming the given array is an `int[]`.) However, my professor said that the number of stars in the definition depends on the number of dimensions in the array. So, an `int[]` would become an `int*`, a `int[][]` would become an `int**`, etc.

So I wrote a small program to test this:

```
void foo(int** ptr)
{    
}

void bar(int* ptr)
{    
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][4];

    foo(arr);
    bar(arr);
}
```

To my surprise, the compiler issued warnings on *both* function calls.

```
main.c:22:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type
      'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    foo(arr);
        ^~~
main.c:8:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'ptr' here
void foo(int** ptr)
         ^
main.c:23:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type
      'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    bar(arr);
        ^~~
main.c:13:15: note: passing argument to parameter 'ptr' here
void bar(int* ptr)
         ^
2 warnings generated.
```

What's going on here? How could you change the function calls so one of them would accept the array?

---

My [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430697/what-is-the-pointer-type-of-a-multidimensional-array-when-passed-to-a-function) got marked as a duplicate, and since I can't figure out how to get the duplicate removed I'm asking it again.

**Edit:** This is *not* a duplicate of [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c) because I'm asking how to change the function calls themselves, not the function signatures. I know one of these functions is correct, I'm just not sure which one or how you would go about calling it.

**Edit 2:** This is a duplicate of my original question, but the original was wrongly marked as a duplicate and couldn't get answered so I re-asked it.

Comment: You get the duplicate closure removed by editing your old question to make it clear that it's not a duplicate (including linking the post that you're referencing) and then waiting for it to get sufficient re-open votes. What you **do not** do is then post the duplicate question again. The [help] has more information about what to do if your question gets closed; it's in the Asking section.

Comment: This is *partly* a duplicate of the question you link to. An array of array is *not* the same as a pointer to pointer. See e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558) for an explanation why.

Comment: The next time a question of yours is closed and you want to have it reopened, do not accept an answer. If you do, you are saying that you are satisfied with it, and therefore there's no reason to reopen it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, my professor said that the number of stars in the definition depends on the number of dimensions in the array. So, an `int[]` would become an `int*`, a `int[][]` would become an `int**`, etc.

I'm really, *really* hoping you simply misunderstood what he was saying, because that's not correct.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  If `T` is an array type, you wind up with a *pointer to an array*, not a pointer to a pointer.

Going through some examples:

```
int arr[10];
...
foo( arr, 10 ); // need to pass number of rows as a separate parameter
```

In the call to `foo`, the expression `arr` has type "10-element array of `int`".  Since it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to type `int *`, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.  Thus, the prototype for `foo` would be

```
void foo( int *arr, size_t rows ); // or int arr[]; it means the same thing in this context
```

Notice that this is the same type as the result of the expression `&arr[0]`. `arr[0]` is an `int` object, so `&arr[0]` gives us an `int *`.  IOW, `arr == &arr[0]`.

So far so good.  Now let's look at a 2D array:

```
int arr[10][20];
...
foo( arr, 10 );
```

In this case, the expression `arr` has type "10-element array of *20-element array of `int`*"; it "decays" to an expression of type "pointer to *20-element array of `int`*"; thus, the prototype for `foo` becomes

```
void foo( int (*arr)[20], size_t rows ); // or int arr[][20]
```

Remember the part above where it says "except when it is the operand of ... the unary `&` operator"?  If we write `&arr[0]`, `arr[0]` has type "20-element array of `int`", but it does *not* automatically decay to a pointer.  So instead of getting an expression of type `int **`, we get an expression of type `int (*)[20]`.  So again, `arr == &arr[0]`.

Now let's look at a 3D array:

```
int arr[10][20][30];
...
foo( arr, 10 );
```

This time, the expression `arr` has type "10-element array of *20-element array of 30-element array of `int`*".  This time, it "decays" to an expression of type "pointer to *20-element array of 30-element array of `int`*", and the prototype is now

```
void foo( int (*arr)[20][30], size_t rows ); // or int arr[][20][30]
```

And once again, `arr[0]` has an array type, so the expression `&arr[0]` gives us the type `int (*)[20][30]`; again, `arr == &arr[0]`.

The pattern for higher-dimensioned arrays should be clear from here on out.

Now, this brings up a minor issue.  A pointer to an `N`-element array is a different type from pointer to an `M`-element array, where `N != M`.  If your function prototype is

```
void foo( int (*)[20], size_t rows );
```

then it will *only* work with `N`x20 arrays; you cannot pass it a pointer to an array with a different outer dimension:

```
void foo( int (*ap)[20], size_t rows );
...
int arr1[10][20];
int arr2[20][20];
int arr3[20][30];

foo( arr1, 10 ); // okay
foo( arr2, 20 ); // okay
foo( arr3, 20 ); // not okay - arr3 has type int (*)[30], which is not *compatible* 
                 // with int (*)[20]
```

**EDIT**

In the case where a function is expecting an `int *` and you have a multi-dimensional array, you'd explicitly pass a pointer to the first element:

```
void foo( int *, size_t size );
...
int arr2[10][20];
int arr3[20][10][5];

foo( &arr2[0][0], sizeof arr2 / sizeof arr2[0][0] );
foo( &arr3[0][0][0], sizeof arr3 / sizeof arr3[0][0][0] );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I specifically remember him saying the line about the number of dimensions being the number of stars in the pointer definition. Thanks for the great explanation though, it's a lot clearer now, +1

Answer (score 2):

Check the data types carefully, you'll get it.

For the function `void bar(int* ptr) {...` it expects an `int *`, and you've got to pass one. Something like

```
 bar (&(arr[0][0]));
```

would do it.

That said, in general, an array is not the same as a pointer. For most of the cases, the array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, but then again, the data types should be same (or at least, *compatible*).

Comment: _Ohhhh_... that makes so much sense. So the one expecting an `int**` is incorrect?

Comment: @Dovahkiin again, check carefully, do you have an `int **` to pass? or is it `int (*)[4]?`

Comment: I guess not... so my professor was wrong?

Comment: @Dovahkiin To elaborate, a pointer to pointer to `int` and a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s...there ought to be some difference, in'nit?

Comment: @Dovahkiin [see this also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30892273/2173917)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, a = [1,2,3]

Here, a is the pointer to the first element of the array.

```
*a = 1 , *(a+1) = 2, *(a+2) = 3.
```

Now , if a is multidimensional array, like a[3][4]

```
*a = a[0][0] , *(a+1) = a[1][0], *(a+2) = a[2][0]

*(*a + 1) = a[0][1], *(*a + 2) = a[0][2]

*(*(a+1) + 1) = a[1][1], *(*(a+1) + 2) = a[1][2]

*(*(a+2) + 1) = a[1][1], *(*(a+2) + 2) = a[1][2]
```

*a + any_number changes the row, but *(*a + any_number) changes the column.

In function, you only pass the pointer to array, here i.e, a.

so ,

```
void bar(*a){
#access elements like told above.
}
```

Double pointer **b, it means it is pointing to another pointer, means, if

```
*b = a
```

b's value is the address of a i.e, *b and a have same values.
But **b has points to where a points.

means **b and *a have same values.