# double pointer (int**) and double brackets to get the value from a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I thought I was OK at C style arrays, apparently not. I can't figure this out.

Say I declare a function

```
void RotateMatrix(int ** matrix, int n)
{
    auto x = matrix[0][0];
}
```

(assume matrix is square). Driving it from the main function

```
void main() 
    {
    int matrix[4][4] = 

    { 
        {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
        {5, 6, 7, 8}, 
        {9, 10, 11, 12}, 
        {13, 14, 15, 16} 
    };

    RotateMatrix((int**) matrix, 4);
}
```

Basically, `matrix[0][1]` results in a buffer overflow. Debugging it, `matrix[0][0]` tries to go to the address `0x0000000200000001`, a combination of the first 8 bytes in the array, presumably as int is 4 bytes and `int*` is 8 bytes, and `int**` is a pointer to a pointer of ints, hence it treats the first 2 matrix entries as `int*`. However, this confused me as answers like bobobobo's on [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c/2829882) seems to show you can use the `int**` approach. I'm confused. I've seen other SO posts say the same thing, so why does it work for them?

I thought `matrix[0][0]` it would do `matrix[0]`'s address plus `offset 0 * sizeof(int)` (which would still be the first element)

Comment: Don't use casts. Whenever you cast, you've misunderstood the type system.

Comment: spidy sense are telling me it might be because of dynamic array allocation where you do actually allocate an array of int* and then for each row an array of ints. Correct?

Comment: Read [AnT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828693/1480131) in the same thread you've linked in your question. `matrix` does not decay in a `int**` but in a `int (*)[4]`.

Comment: If you removed the cast, the compiler clearly shows you the error.  When you applied the cast, you told the compiler to "shut up, leave me alone, I know what I'm doing".  The compiler knew better, tried to let you know, but you didn't listen and went ahead with the cast.

Answer (score 2):

An array of array decays not into a pointer to pointer, but into a pointer to array. So the array `int matrix[4][4]` decays not into `int **`, but into `int (*)[4]`.

That is why you need to get rid of the cast and change the signature of `RotateMatrix`.