# call 2D pointer/array from 3D pointer/array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

For each time step, I have a 2D matrix `a[ix][iz]` with `ix` varying from `0` to `nx-1` and `iz` varying from `0` to `nz-1`.

To assemble the matrix of all the time steps, I define a 3D pointer `***b` of length `nx*nz*nt`. At time `it` the matrix can be represented by `b[ix][iz][it]` with `ix` varying from `0` to `nx-1` and `iz` varying from `0` to `nz-1`.

In the time loop, I have to deliver the 2D array/pointer at time `it` to the function `void func(**ptr)`. Because `b` is a 3D pointer/array, how can I call it in the main code? Like `func(b[it]);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could restructure your matrix as `b[it][ix][iz]` instead of `b[ix][iz][it]`. This way, you'd have an array of 2D matrices, allowing you to pass in the 2D matrix at any given timestep using `b[it]`.

Otherwise, if you keep your matrix as-is, you'd have to construct the 2D array at time `it`, then pass that into `func()` - that's extra computation that you can avoid by restructuring your 3D matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use your `b` to just store pointers to matrices like this:

In each timestep, copy your matrix `a` and insert the pointer to the copy of matrix `a` into `b`.
Then, you can pass `b[i]` over to your function `func(b[i])` .

That is basically what frsim suggests as well.
In code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TIME 5

void func(int array[2][3]) {

    for(size_t x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {

        for(size_t y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
            printf("%i ", array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    printf("\n");

}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

   int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

   int b[MAX_TIME][2][3] = {0};

   for(size_t time = 0; time < MAX_TIME; ++time) {

       /* Calculate your new version of `a` here */

       a[1][0] = time;

       memcpy(b[time], a, sizeof(a));
       printf("%zu ", sizeof(a));

   }

   for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_TIME; ++i) {
       printf("time: %zu \n", i);
       func(b[i]);
   }

}
```

Arrays bear a lot of pitfalls, in particular, an array is **not** a pointer.

But: If you pass an array to a function, what happens is that not the array itself will be passed into the function, but a pointer to the array.
The same would happen with a two-dimensional array: When calling a function with a two-dimensional array, what is passed into the function is not the array, but a pointer, and this pointer is still just `int *` and not `int **`... See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c)

Comment: "but a pointer to the array" --> "but a pointer to the first element of the array".