# Why can't I pass and edit this array to a function?

Tags: c

My previous question was answered but I have another in the same vein. Why does the code not work when I try to use a multi-dimensional array?

```
void change(int *);

int main(void){
    int array[1][2] = {2};

    printf("%d", array[1][2]);
    change(array);
    printf("%d", array[1][2]);
}

void change(int *array){
    array[1][2] = 4;
}
```

Comment: `change` takes an `int` argument, not `int *`, so that'a a deal breaker right out of the gate. Second, `*array[0]` is certainly wrong, even after  fixing the parameter type to proper `int *`. It would be `array[0] = ...` *or* `*array = ...` to set the first element, but not both. I think a thorough review of arrays, function parameters and passing the former as arguments to the latter, are on your upcoming agenda.

Comment: From point of view inside of `change(int)`, what would make the parameter "array" an array, apart from the name which the compiler ignores?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828648/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Now you've completely altered the type of array declared (was `int[2]`, now its `int[1][2]`. Further, your two `printf` commands are both using invalid indexes on the `array` variable. C arrays of dim `n` are indexed using `0..(n-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use asterisks for parameter at the time of declaration and definition.
For making array[0]=4, you only need to assign 4 to array[0] without asterisk. So your code should be:

```
void change(int *);

int main(void){
    int array[1] = {2};

    printf("%d", array[0]);
    change(array);
    printf("%d", array[0]);
}

void change(int *array){
    array[0] = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`    void change(int*);

```
int main(void){
    int array[1] = {2};

    printf("%d\n", array[0]);
    change(array);
    printf("%d\n", array[0]);
}

void change(int* array)
{
    array[0] = 4;
    *(array + 0) = 4;
}
```

don't put '&' in array. it is pointer. so you must change your function "change(int ...) to change(int* )"

and to change array[0] you don't need to put * on array. it's an array!. or to use * . then you must add n-th element number.

Answer (score 0):

C language uses `pass by value`.
So, You have to receive the address of array as argument.

```
void change(int *, int);

int main(void) {
    int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    printf("%d", array[1]);
    change(array, 1);
    printf("%d", array[1]);
}

void change(int *array, int index) {
    *(array+index) = 4;
}
```

For the multi dimension, You should pass a size of column.
I made 2 samples as `change` and `change2`.
I think you can understand `change` well.
But, In case of `change2`, `array` has a head address of memory in `array[2][3]` and it has `6` integers by `2x3`. So, you can calculate.

```
void change(int array[2][3], int, int, int);
void change2(int *, int, int, int, int);

int main(void) {
    int array[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, {4, 5, 6} };

    printf("%d", array[1][1]);
    change(array, 1, 1, 10);
    printf("%d", array[1][1]);
    change2((int *)array, 3, 1, 1, 20);
    printf("%d", array[1][1]);
}

void change(int array[2][3], int row, int col, int value) {
    array[row][col] = value;
}

void change2(int *array, int size_col, int row, int col, int value) {
    *(array + row*size_col + col) = value;
}
```

Comment: How would this work if the array had more than one dimension?