# How to pass 2 dimension arrays to function in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c)
>   [Converting multidimensional arrays to pointers in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584100/converting-multidimensional-arrays-to-pointers-in-c)

Hi,

I try to pass 2 dimension arrays to function in C, and 
the following code works

```
 void printArray(int a[][4], int size) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < size; ++i) {
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < size; ++j) {
                printf("%d,", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

but if I replace `"int a[][4]"` to `"int **a"`
it won't work, can anyone tell what's the difference ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Obligatory link: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html.  Everything you need to know should be in there; I won't bother writing it all out here...