# Passing multi-dimensional array to function in c?

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have an array of string declared like so:

```
char parts[PART_COUNT][PART_MAX];
```

Then i made a function which takes a string and a array of strings and splits it into those parts, which is declared like this:

```
WORD PartString(const char *str, char **parts, char sep);
```

I can seem to read at parts[i][j], but if i try to assign like this:

```
parts[i][j] = str[x];
```

I get this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x012614d8 in remote.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.

Can anyone tell me a way to do this in C? thanks.

Comment: `char parts[M][N]` is not the same as `char **parts`; if you've performed a cast in order to get the compiler to stop complaining, then that will be the cause of your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting multidimensional arrays to pointers in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584100/converting-multidimensional-arrays-to-pointers-in-c)

Comment: compiler isn't complaining, i passed simply as PartString(buffer, parts, '.');

Comment: That should definitely cause a compiler warning or error message.

Comment: the solution to the duplicate you linked, is to use a template. and its in c++

Comment: The accepted answer does not involve templates.

Comment: You urgently need to deal with the fact that your compiler is broken.

Comment: @David: or perhaps its warnings are just not turned up enough.  Kaije, if you're using gcc to compile, add the options `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: i'm in visual studio, just enabled warnings, and it does warn me about it  'char **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [4][1024]'

Comment: @John You are right. C is more permissive. Treat warnings as errors is the way forward and you could argue doing so is fixing the compiler!!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define PART_MAX      1024
#define PART_COUNT    4
```

Ok, managed to fix it, i had my compiler warnings off and when i turned them back on i got this:

```
'char **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [4][1024]'
```

Heres the new declaration which lets me modify the strings in the array:

```
WORD PartString(const char *str, char (*parts)[PART_MAX], char sep)
```

THen i just pass as:

```
PartString(buffer, parts, '.');
```