# How to access value in array from a pointer that is a member of a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

I've searched stackoverflow and seen every combination of the words in my question, but not the question I have.

I have an array of ints, it happens to be a 2d array.

```
const int themap[something][something] = { {0, ...
```

I have a struct that I want to have a pointer to this array in my program

```
typedef struct {
int** mymap;
} THE_STRUCT
```

In my program I want to iterate over the values of the array through the struct's pointer, but my data seems to be corrupted if i try to access it through the . syntax

```
int value;
THE_STRUCT mystruct;
mystruct = (int**) themap;

...
//access the map data from mystruct's pointer?
value = mystruct.mymap[x][y];
//doesn't seem to return correct values
```

Taking the struct out of the picture the same exact function works if I directly use the array (as a global variable)

```
int value;
...
//access the map directly
value = themap[x][y]
//everyone is happy!
```

I would like to use the struct as in reality it will carry other information as well as the fact that I will need to be able to assign the pointer to other arrays with different data.

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8203730/900873

Comment: `themap` can be interpreted as a pointer, and any pointer-pointer conversions are legal if casted in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two-dimensional array is not the same as an `int **`.  If you want to store a pointer to it inside the `struct`, you can do something like:

```
const int themap[something1][something2] = { {0, ...

typedef struct {
    const int (*mymap)[something2];
} THE_STRUCT;

...

THE_STRUCT my_struct;
my_struct.mymap = themap;

...

int value = my_struct.mymap[x][y];
```

It *is* possible to use an `int **`, but it requires some effort:

```
const int themap[something1][something2] = { {0, ...
const int * themapPointerArray[something1] = {themap[0], themap[1], ..., themap[something1 - 1]};

typedef struct {
    const int **mymap;
} THE_STRUCT;

...

THE_STRUCT my_struct;
my_struct.mymap = themapPointerArray;

...

int value = my_struct.mymap[x][y];
```

Comment: what if I don't want to hard code the array length 'something2' in the struct as it might be different?

Comment: Then you should linearize the array -- `const int themapLinear[something1 * something2] = {0, ...}` so that you only need to store a `const int *`.  You would then replace `themap[x][y]` with `themapLinear[(x * something2) + y]` and here `something2` doesn't need to be known until runtime (and can, e.g., be passed into a function).

Comment: The problem is that interpreting something like `themap[x][y]`, if `themap` is a two-dimensional array, requires knowing how many elements are in each row.  The compiler will need to know that at compile time.

Comment: It _is_ possible to use an `int **` and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, that makes sense, I could limit a fixed number of elements in each row in my case I guess, so I will try that out. Thanks to you and nneonneo for your advice.

Comment: The solution works. However I do receivce a compiler warning:  "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" on the line that assigns my struct's pointer to 'themap'

Comment: That's kind of an important warning.  Maybe I did something wrong, though I'm not seeing anything obvious at this late hour.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the compiler version? GCC 4.5.2

Comment: No, are you using the code with `const int (*mymap)[something2]
` or the code with `const int **mymap`?

Comment: ah ok: 'const int (*mymap)[something2]'

Comment: I just wrote up a quick test case and got no such warnings.  I can't sensibly put my test code in a comment (unfortunately) and am hesitant to update my answer after it's been accepted, but perhaps you should post your code as a new question.  If there's an error, it likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Ah, good.  The `const` tells the compiler that you won't modify the values and that it can assume that to be the case.  It will warn you if you try.  There _are_ ways around this, but it's still good to declare arrays of and pointers to `const` data if you have no need to modify the stored data, as it helps prevent bugs and makes it easier for different pieces of code to use the same array(s).

Answer (score 3):

A multidimensional array `int [][]` and a double-indirect pointer `int **` are two completely different things.

A multidimensional array is, to C, a one-dimensional array indexed in a different way. Say `x` is `int [3][4]`. Then, `x` contains 12 sequentially-packed elements, and `x[1][2]` is just the 6th element of that one-dimensional array.

A double-indirect pointer treated as a 2-dimensional array is an array of *pointers to arrays*. So, if `y` is `int **`, then `y[1][2]` means "the third element of the array pointed to by the second element of `y`".

You cannot therefore convert between `int [][]` and `int **`, since they just represent different things (your casting of `int [][]` to `int **` causes the integers in the `int [][]` array to be treated as pointers, which will inevitably crash).

Instead, you can cast `int [M][N]` as `int (*)[N]` -- a pointer to an array of `N`-length arrays.