# what is wrong when i'm trying to access this array (2d ) in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

below is the code that I'm trying to run

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo(int **a){
    cout<<*(a+3)<<endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    std::cout << sizeof(a);
    foo((int **)a);
}
```

when I have four elements in this array, shouldn't the value *(a+3) return a value 4, instead of that its returning an address and when i try to dereference that address (i.e. **(a+3)) i get segfault 11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conversion of 2D array to pointer-to-pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203700/conversion-of-2d-array-to-pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: That you had to smash that inappropriate cast into that code to get it to compile to be your first hint something is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you are defining an array of arrays of integers. It can decay to a pointer to an array of integers, but it will *not* decay into a pointe to a pointer of integers.

It will help if you draw the memory layout:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1    |    2    |    3    |    4    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

If you let it decay into a pointer-to-array-of-integer:

```
int (*pa)[2] = a;

+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  pa[0]            |  pa[1]            |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1    |    2    |    3    |    4    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Note how `sizeof(*pa) = 2 * sizeof(int)`. Each of these values can decay into a pointer to integer, but never into a pointer to a pointer:

```
int *p = pa[0];
```

Anyway, you can cast the decayed pointer-to-array-of-integer into a pointer to integers and access the four values directly:

```
int *p = (int*)a;
std::cout << p[3] << std::endl;
std::cout << *(p + 3) << std::endl;
```

The memory will be like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   p[0]  |   p[1]  |   p[2]  |   p[3]  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1    |    2    |    3    |    4    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

But if you cast it into a `int**` you will get meaningless values, because in memory there are no pointers, just integers.

Comment: The value indeed is at the location a + 3, because a is also the location of the first element, so the problem with his code in particular is that it is formatted as an address, instead of a number when printed.

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte: Unless `sizeof(int*) != sizeof(int)`. Then you will be way out of the proper location.

Answer (score 2):

A array is not a pointer.  Yes it can decay to a pointer that does not mean it is one.  If you want to pass a 2d array then you can use

```
int foo(int a[][2]);
```

or if you want to take any size array then you can use

```
template<std::size_t N>
int foo(int a[][N]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dereference `int**` you get `int*`. However, you are dereferencing a location with a value `4` that is interpreted as `int*`. That's why cout prints `0x4`, because it formats it as an address. Try taking `int*` as parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo(int *a){
    cout<<*(a+3)<<endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    std::cout << sizeof(a);
    foo((int *)a);
}
```

It prints 4 then.

---

This is just an example of how to fix up this piece of code in particular, and is not the right way of doing things. Also as @rodrigo stated in the comments of his answer, if the size of an int is not equal to the size of its pointer, this is not going to work. I just wanted to show you why you thought it was printing an address - because it is being interpreted as one.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing too far. a already points to the first element in the array.  So **a treats the first value in the array as an address instead of a value. Try

```
    foo((int *)a)
```