# Why we don't need number of column when passing the dynamic 2d array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Lets say that I have two arrays and I am passing them to a function :

```
void func(int arr1[][4], int **arr2) { // <- I need to give n in only one, why?
...
}
int main() {
    int n = 5, m = 4;
    int arr1[n][m];
    int **arr2 = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        arr2[i] = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    func(arr1, arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't we treat both the array passing in a similar way?

Edit : There was an error in the code.

Comment: `arr2` isn't an array, but a pointer, in fact a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: In either case the function needs to know the size of the pointed at data somehow. There's no way around that no matter syntax. So ideally you would write something like `void func(size_t x, size_t y, int arr[x][y])`.

Comment: Also see [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) to unlearn your misunderstanding about dynamic 2d arrays.

Comment: Note that `arr1` in `main` can't be passed to `func`; it expects an `int arr1[][5]` and yet you have, in effect, `int arr1[5][4];` in `main()` (except it is a variably qualified array, not a regular array of fixed size).  A world of pain awaits you.

Comment: Also, your code is strictly C code (C99 or C11 code).  C++ compilers are not required to allow your array in `main()`.  If `n` and `m` were const-qualified, the issue would be different.  And GCC/G++ allows variably qualified arrays unless you specify `-pedantic` but there are other C++ compilers in this world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acually the opposite of what you're saying is the case: You don't have to pass the number of rows. Assume that array indices work like this:

```
int arr[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL]; /* with both 3 */

           col
     --------------->
    | 0,0   0,1   0,2
row | 1,0   1,1   1,2
    V 2,0   2,1   2,2
```

When you pass `int arr[][MAX_COL]` the compiler know where the next row will begin when you address like `arr[row][col]` for example.

If you would do that manually with a pointer it would look like: `&arr[0][0] + row * MAX_COL + col`. In that example you also have to know the column size `MAX_COL` of the array to calculate the next row.

The reason for this is, that an array is continuous in memory. The above array is represented in memory like:

```
|     row = 0     |     row = 1     |     row = 2     |
| 0,0   0,1   0,2 | 1,0   1,1   1,2 | 2,0   2,1   2,2 |
```

The compiler does also have to know the row offset because when you pass an array declared as `int arr[MAX_SIZE]` to the function `void foo (int arr[])`, it decays into a pointer to the beginning of the array `int* arr`. In case of arrays of arrays (2D arrays), it decays to a pointer to its first element as well, which is a pointer to a single array `int (*arr)[MAX_COL]`.

**In short:** With `int arr[][MAX_COL]` the compiler have all informations needed to address the array with `arr[row][col]`.

Comment: I understood your answer and it certainly helped. A better in short if I may suggest so, will be, "In simpler way, int **arr2 is a 2-d grid of ints formed using pointers while int arr1[][] is a 1-d datastruct of ints with the information of where the row ends. " If I understood it wrong, then please correct me.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal: Don't know what you mean by 2-d grid and 1-d datastruct. Actually all the arrays, 1D, 2D, 3D, etc. are stored continuous in memory.

Comment: Is pointer to pointer continuous, because each row is allocated using malloc in each iteration, so there should be a jump between the address of last element of first row and first element of second row ?

Comment: Yes you are right! Remember: **`int** arr != int arr[row][col]`**. A pointer to pointer is not a fixed size 2D array [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203700/conversion-of-2d-array-to-pointer-to-pointer). A fixed size 2D array is as already said equivalent to `int (*arr)[MAX_COL]` which is a pointer to a single array. A pointer to a pointer `int** arr` is not garantueed to be continuous as you said it's dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the opposite, you can omit only one of the index (in case of a multi-dimensional array), the innermost one.

This is because, arrays, while passed as function arguments, decays to a pointer to the first element. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> **Except** when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is **converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. [...]

thus, a notation like

```
 void func(int arr1[][5], int **arr2)    //an array of array of 5 ints
```

and

```
 void func(int (*arr1) [5], int **arr2)  //pointer to the starting element of an array of 5 ints
```

are equivalent.

Comment: Please explain this a bit more : 'decays to a pointer to the first element'.

Comment: Isn't it called the *outermost* one (the omittable)? I belived it was referred to the memory layout, not the position in code between tokens.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal Actually a function array *parameter* is "adjusted" to a pointer to the type of element of the array. So `int[42`] is *adjusted* to `int*`. Array *decay* is what happens when you call such a function with an array as *argument*. And a "2D array" is an array of arrays.

Comment: @cmaster Thanks, that was a typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually have only one array of ints (i.e. `int arr1[][5]`) and one pointer to a pointer of an int, i.e. `int **arr2`. Even if an array like `arr1[10][5]`, when passed as argument to a function, decays to a pointer to the beginning of the memory where the elements reside, there is a (big) difference in memory layout and in the way how a compiler treats access to these pointers.

BTW, in main it should be `int n=5,m=4;int arr1[m][n]`, not `int n=5,m=4;int arr1[n][m]`.

Concerning memory layout:

A 2D integer array of the form `int [10][5]` is represented as 10 consecutive "rows", each comprising 5 "columns" (i.e. integral values). The size of this array is `10 * 5 * sizeof(int)`, and the size of one "row" is `5 * sizeof(int)`.

A pointer to a pointer to int `int **p` is just a single pointer; its size is `sizeof(int**)`, even if you have "malloced" a sequence of integral pointers lile `p = malloc(10 * sizeof (int*))`; Note "*" in `sizeof(int *)`, as you create a sequence of pointers to integers, not a sequence of integers. That's the main difference in memory layout: It's not a 2D array of integers, but a 1D array of pointers to integers. And if one actually had allocated 10 "rows" for "10" integers, each row could be located in a different portion of memory. The space needed for managing such a (spreaded) amount of 10x5 integral values is "10*sizeof(int*) + 10*5*sizeof(int)".

Concerning access:

Let's assume a variable of type `int arr[][5]`, which is a 2D-array of integers, where the size of a column is `5` and the number of rows is not determined. Informally, an access like `int x = arr[3][4]` is translated into an access the `(3*5 + 4)`th element of the array, i.e. "row times rowsize plus column"; Note that - based on this formula - the compiler does not need to know how many rows the the array actually has.

In contrast, let's assume a variable of type `int **p`. You can think of an access like `x = p[3][4]` as being equivalent to `int *r = p[3]; int x = r[4]`; Note that `r` is of type `int *`, i.e. it is a pointer, and `r[4]` then dereferences this pointer and returns an integral value.

This is rather informally described. 
Yet the main issue is that the memory layout of an `arr[][5]` contains consecutive integral values only, whereas `int **arrr` may be a seqence of pointers (or even just one such pointer), each of them probably pointing to a sequence of integral values (or just one integral value).