# Assign array to double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

This is part of an assignment.
I currently at the part where I have to read in a `.csv` file into following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    double **data;
} Matrix;
```

The `.csv` file has for example 3 rows and 3 columns:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and would look like this as a 2d array:

```
double array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

and now I would want to assign my array to the Matrix like this:

```
function someFunction(Matrix *m) {
    //...
    double array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    A->data = array;
    A->n = 3;
    //...
}
```

But assigning `array` to `data` is not working as I get following error using `gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors`:

`error: assignment to ‘double **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘double *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   79 |   A->data = array;`

How can I resolve this problem? Part of the assignment is that gcc is not allowed to show any warnings when using -Wall and -pedantic-erros, so hacks aren't allowed.

Comment: Why not just use a double*, allocate the memory based on (rows * cols * sizeof(double)), then manage the index yourself with ((row * 3) + col) ?  double array[] = (double*){{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

Comment: @SPlatten the assignment requires me to use the above mentioned struct. so I have to use a double pointer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203700/conversion-of-2d-array-to-pointer-to-pointer

Comment: Keep it as it is but change your data declaration to be double* data, then assign with : A->data = (double*)array;  Modify your structure to include a bit more detail, instead of n, add rows and cols both of which in this case will be 3.

Comment: @sailfish009 thanks that link solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conversion of 2D array to pointer-to-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203700/conversion-of-2d-array-to-pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: @AngryRedPanda You need to be very careful if you are trying to follow that link. You can't define a local variable and assign it to your `data` pointer. The local variable is only valid inside the function. So you need to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: `data` is not an array, nor is it a pointer to an array, nor can it be used as an array. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double**` is a pointer to pointer. Of course the (outer) pointer could point to some array, too:

```
double* array[7];
double** pointer = array;
```

Now each of the pointers in `array` could point to other arrays as well:

```
double valueArray[12]
double* pointerArray[10];

double** pointer = array;
pointer[0] = valueArray; // equivalent to pointerArray[0] = ...
```

Two-dimenstional arrays are not arrays of pointers, though, they are arrays of arrays, and pointer to first element is of different type:

```
double array[10][12];
double(*pointer)[12] = array;
```

Trying to cover arbitrary size matrices produces some trouble, though:

```
struct Matrix
{
    size_t n;
    double(*data)[n]; // you cannot exchange arbitrary pointers,
                      // you need a compile time constant!
};
```

Be aware that this is different from VLA in function parameters, where you could have

```
void f(size_t n, int(*data)[n]);
```

Then it looks as if you get pretty much into trouble already with the bit of code you presented:

```
void someFunction(Matrix* m)
{
    double array[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    m->data = array; // assuming you meant m instead of A
                     // and you did adjust the pointer type already appropriately
}
```

`array` has local storage duration and will be destroyed as soon as you return from the function, resulting in a dangling pointer in `m` and in undefined behaviour, if you dereference that pointer after returning from function.

So you would need to `malloc` an array of sufficient size instead. **But don't forget to free it again then, too!**

So if you don't want to go the pointer to pointer way:

```
double** array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * n);
array[0] = malloc(sizeof(**array) * n);
// ...
```

which would allow for the `m->data[x][y]` syntax, then you should stick to the one-dimensional array approach:

```
struct Matrix
{
    size_t n;
    double* data;
};
```

and maybe some accessor function:

```
double get(struct Matrix* m, size_t row, size_t column)
{
    return m->data[row * m->n + column];
}
```

which would get around the double pointer indirection and thus be faster (actually, that's exactly the same calculation that occurs under the hoods with a true two-dimensional array, i. e. not the pointer to pointer variant).

Comment: For the last "mangled 2D array" version, you should use flexible array members, so that the data is allocated together with the struct.

Comment: @Lundin Nice idea – suppose we should make `n` const then as well... But not suitable for *every* use case (e. g. arrays of matrices; enlarging matrix size would require creating new objects, ...).